# Angular2 - How to get properties from class with getter and setter?

Tags: angular, typescript, reflection

I am trying to access class properties and i able to do that. but the problem is i am not able to access get and set method from class.

```
export class PageModel {
    public ParentID: string = null;
    public Type: string = null;
    public Order: number = 0;

    public get ApplicationManager(): ApplicationManager {
        if (ApplicationManager.Current != null && ApplicationManager.Current.Model != null) {
            return ApplicationManager.Current;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Many more methods below.
}
```

Below is logic for fetching properties from class.

```
protected GetProperties(obj: any): Array<string> {
    let properties: Array<string> = new Array<string>();

    if (obj != null && typeof obj == "object") {
        for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(
                 properties.push(property);                    
            }
        }
    }

    if (properties != null)
        properties.sort();

    return properties;
}
```

In above logic i able to get list of properties but i am not getting get and set method.

Comment: why do you expect them to see as properties - they are functions essentially!

Comment: I tried to fetch functions from class but there is so many functions inside class so if there is some way to fetch only getter and setter with other properties then it would be great.